# ReportLab letter spacing in Paragraph

Tags: reportlab

Is it possible to set up letter/char spacing in Paragraph Style? 
I tried to use `spaceShrinkage`
but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Any luck on this? I have the exact same question.

Comment: @DanceParty, does my answer suits the question?

Comment: I think it might work. I ended up using style.spaceShrinkage.

Comment: FYI, it looks like someone made it work, but the change wasn't adopted https://reportlab-users.reportlab.narkive.com/Fpe2ho4J/adding-charspace-as-a-paragraph-style-attribute 

That's not all that helpful if, like me, you don't want to used an unofficially patched reportlab. But if you're desperate, this might be your solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf), p. 30:

> The `setCharSpace` method adjusts one of the parameters of text -- the inter-character spacing.

It's followed by a code sample:

```
def charspace(canvas):
    from reportlab.lib.units import inch
    textobject = canvas.beginText()
    textobject.setTextOrigin(3, 2.5*inch)
    textobject.setFont("Helvetica-Oblique", 10)
    charspace = 0
    for line in lyrics:
        textobject.setCharSpace(charspace)
        textobject.textLine("%s: %s" %(charspace,line))
        charspace = charspace+0.5
```

Comment: The question asks about character spacing in a `ParagraphStyle`, which could be applied to a `Paragraph` object. I don't think `setCharSpace` can be used on a `ParagraphStyle` or `Paragraph`. If it can, could you please show how?

Comment: @jpobst, you're right, this looks like a workaround at best.

Answer (score 0):

`can.drawString(self, x, y, text, mode=None, charSpace=0, direction=None, wordSpace=None)`

> Example:
> `can.drawString(self, 200, 200, 'text', None, 2, None, 3)`